# Renaming a Branch and Pushing the 'New' Branch to Remote

Tags: git, version-control

In the DEV environment on the project I am currently working on, I am running a virtual machine on my Mac to simulate Visual Studio the application churns on.  The virtual machine was mounted onto my Mac with a Git environment already created and configured.  I'd like to distinguish my version of the branch that I've started working on (the current local branch is called 'master') by renaming it to something else.  At the same time, I want to make sure the remote 'master' branch is perserved since this is someone else's branch.

From what I understand, I should rename my local branch by using

```
git branch -m my-new-branch-name
```

I can then do a pull -> push and my new branch would be accessible and my working branch / the remote name for it would be 'my-new-branch-name'.

Is this the right course of action here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a branch from master's current location, your local one will be named `my-new-branch-name`, and after pushing, the remote version will be `origin/my-new-branch-name`, assuming your remote is named `origin` (which, I believe, is the default).

`master` should be the primary branch. If you're working with someone else who also needs to work on a separate branch, they should probably be branching off of `master` as well. Of course, this all depends on the pattern your team uses for version control.

[Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/software-branching-and-parallel-universes.html) has a great article explaining the most commonly-used patterns for how to use branches in version control. I recommend reading it and determining which pattern your team uses or would work best for your team.

For example, At my work, we use one branch per task, merging them in to `master` for testing shortly before deploying to production. Sometimes we will make a small (1-2 lines) or time-critical change directly to `master`, but we always require a co-worker to review the changes before committing them.

As far as git specifically goes, your plan sounds about right, other than your remote branch being `origin/my-new-branch-name` instead of just `my-new-branch-name`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are doing the correct thing. Thats the short answer.

However, if you are new to git, you might get caught or stuck, so I'll walk you through the process here.

If you have not yet committed your changes you can do the following on the remote:

```
git stash
git checkout -b my-new-branch-name master 
git stash apply
git add . 
git commit -m 'committing new changes' 
git push origin my-new-branch-name
```

The git-stash command just stores your changes temporarily so you can checkout safely, and then git-stash apply reapplies them. This only works for uncommitted changes.

If you have already committed your changes to master, you will want to simply create the branch the same way your original post says, but then you probably also want to remove your changes from the local master branch.

```
git branch my-new-branch-name master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will create your new branch with the new commits, and then reset your local master branch to whatever was in the remote master branch.

Now with that done, you can go to your local machine (or any other clone of the same repo), and pull down that branch.

```
git fetch
git checkout my-new-branch-name
```